# Buildroot only builds Rootfs, now what?

Tags: linux, x86, buildroot, rootfs

I have been working with Buildroot on my Ubuntu system, and the output from the hour long make process only generated a rootfs.tar file. Should I start from the beginning again, or is there something quicker I can do?

The architecture I am building is x86.

I tried searching online, but there were no good answers to my question. I have already tried rebuilding it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? the rootfs.tar file is an archive of the rootfs you ask buildroot to build. You can untar it in some directory and look at its contents

Comment: It just shows the whole filesystem a regular OS would have. Like /usr and /bin and /etc. How should I run this in VMWare Workstation 17 though? If you know how please write an answer in the answer section.

Comment: Also gives this error: linux/linux.mk:606: *** No kernel defconfig name specified, check your BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG setting.  Stop. I think this has something to do with this issue. It cannot build the .img or iso because of that (i think, all the tutorials have more items than just the rootfs) so where do i change that? Or is there also another part to the problem? @droptop

Comment: you only build a rootfs. You also need a kernel. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/cIkTh3Xp3dA?list=PLdGYE1NpnTz1-F6hk2D_DgxeTCJEKWqwE)

Comment: Could you tell me how to build the kernel. Cross compiling on a non arm distro (Ubuntu 22.04) making x86 @droptop to fix that error. Is there a file where I can simply input some options? If so , please tell me where it is and what to do.